# Java split() has space at index 0

Tags: java, string, split

Can someone explain to me what would cause split() to index a space at index [0]? The value I'm sending in is using the trim(), so even if it does have a space it gets removed prior to splitting. However, it is still indexing space at 0.

```
public void firstName(){


    System.out.printf("Enter your First Name:");
    firstName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();

}

public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}


public String splitFirstName(getInput input){

    String x = input.getFirstName();

    String[] splitValue = x.split("");

    String myfirst = splitValue[0];

    return myfirst;

}
```

Comment: Use string.split("(?!^)") to exclude the leading empty string

Comment: this worked @dragon66, however can you explain why there is an empty leading index?

Comment: If you split using an empty string as a delimiter, you can imagine there is another empty string in front of it at the beginning of the string. Actually there is one at the end of the string, but Java discards the trailing one as it does with white spaces. In fact you can even keep the trailing white spaces by giving a negative split limit as in string.split(delimiter, -1)

Comment: thanks @dragon66, this is just always assumed, the preceding empty string?

Comment: I don't think so. If you try this: System.out.print("Hello World".split(" ").length); The value is 2: [Hello,World], no extra empty string. It happens to be associated with the empty string delimiter you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a space as the delimiter.  You have an empty string.

```
String[] splitValue = x.split(""); //<-- this should be x.split(" ");
```

Comment: i am trying to split a word into an array of each letter...thats why there is ("") instead of (" "). If i place the space it just calls the entire word instead of the first letter at the index[0]

Comment: @Srmuhs char[] charArray = yourString.toCharArray();

Comment: @Srmuhs, You can also do `String myfirst = x.Substring(0,1);` to get the first letter.  That seems to be all your code is doing.